# Mpif90 does not compile properly after updating to Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, mpi, gfortran, macos-big-sur

I recently upgraded to Big Sur and am having trouble running a code on mpi. I am running a test code with the following command:

```
mpif90 -o test.f90 ./test
```

I receive the following error:

```
-bash: mpif90: command not found
```

I have updated homebrew and macports yet am unable to solve the problem. I suspect it has something to do with an incorrect path name somewhere. Any ideas? Thank you.

@Oo.oO Thank you. When configuring the build of gcc (per the link in your comment) by the command:

```
 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local/gcc/gcc-9.2.0 \
 --enable-checking=release \
 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran \
 --disable-multilib \
 --with-sysroot=$HOME/opt/usr/local/gcc_system_root \
 --program-suffix=-9.2.0
```

the following error occurs:

```
 configure: error: in `$HOME/opt/src/gcc/gcc-9.2.0/build':
 configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I have updated Xcode (Version 12.3). Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: You can always try to build everything from sources (I am referring here to MPI): https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/

Comment: first things first. How did you install GNU compilers MPI? is this from brew? if so, what does `which gfortran` and `which mpicc` returns?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I installed openmpi Version 2.0.2 with the latest updates of homebrew. `which gfortran` returns `/usr/local/bin/gfortran` and `which mpicc` returns the command line.

Comment: this is odd since brew provides Open MPI `4.0.5`. I'd try to uninstall and reinstall `open-mpi` with brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there were other `/bin/` directories that had older versions of gcc and  openmpi. When updating, the new files from `/lib/` directories needed to be trasnfered to the `/Cellar/` directories. The problem is fixed when first uninstalling all old macports and compilers with incorrect files and/or paths as `sudo port -fp uninstall installed`, and `brew uninstall openmpi`, and `brew uninstall gcc`. Then reinstall new homebrew compilers `brew install gcc`, `brew install openmpi`. This gives the correct paths with configured files when submitting a make file, or in this case, using the `mpif90` command.